# Cannot access li tags in my template view using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have created a master view and subview but, it seems that I cannot access my li tags(subview) within the ul tag(master view) that I appended my subview too. Any suggestions pointing me in the right direction would be awesome! Thank you!

## Views

```
// View for all people
CardAppInitilazer.cardApp.Views.Peoples = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: 'ul.card-grid',
    peopleCollection:function() {
        var people = new CardAppInitilazer.cardApp.Collections.People;
        var getPeople = people.fetch();

        return getPeople;
    },
    render: function() {
        var _self = this;


        _self.peopleCollection().then(function(person) {
            // console.log(person);

            _.each(person, function(model) {
                // console.log(model);

                var peopleView = new peopleInstance({model:model});
                console.log(peopleView);

                _self.$el.append(peopleView.render().el);
            }.bind(this));

        }, function( model, response ) {
            console.log(response + ' could not load model ' + model);
        });

        return this;
    },
    initialize:function() {
        this.render();
    }
});


//View for people
CardAppInitilazer.cardApp.Views.People = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: 'li',

  className:'card-list',

  template: _.template($('#peopleTemplate').html()),

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));

    return this;
  }

});

var peoplesView = new CardAppInitilazer.cardApp.Views.Peoples;
var peopleInstance = CardAppInitilazer.cardApp.Views.People;
```

## Template

```
<ul class="card-grid"></ul>
            <script id="peopleTemplate" type="text/template">
                <a href="#" data-largesrc="<%= image %>" data-title="<%= image %>" data-description="<%= description %>" class="card-content">
                    <h2><%= title %></h2>
                    <img src="<%= image %>" alt="<%= title %>"> 
                </a>
            </script>
```

Comment: Where is the code that tries to acces `<li>` ..?

Comment: Is it not `peopleView.el` that you are after?